# How to convert std::views::join result to string_view at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I want to make the whole code work as `constexpr`.

Here's what works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view words{"Just some sentence I got from a friend."};
    auto rng = words | std::views::split(' ') | std::views::take(4) | std::views::join;
    std::string_view first_four_words{&*rng.begin(), std::ranges::distance(rng)};
    std::cout << first_four_words << std::endl;
}
```

But If I add `constexpr` to the `rng` and `first_four_words` lines, I get compilation error. I thought maybe `cbegin()` would solve it, but I wasn't able to compile it with `cbegin` regardless of the const qualifier, since it refuses to take `rng`...

So, is there a way to make it work as `constexpr`?

And as an aside, is there a more elegant way to build this `string_view`? The `&*` is particularly ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this is to shove it in a function, like so:

```cpp
constexpr std::string_view first_n_words(std::string_view str, size_t n) {    
    auto first_n = str
                | rv::split(' ')
                | rv::take(n)
                | rv::join;   

    auto const len = std::min(str.size(), std::ranges::distance(first_n) + n - 1);
    return std::string_view(&*first_n.begin(), len);
}
```

This doesn't compile right now, because gcc doesn't yet implement [P2231](https://wg21.link/p2231), which is required in order to for `join_view` to work at compile time, and then libstdc++ needs to change their implementation of `emplace_deref` to both mark it `constexpr` (as it is [defined](https://eel.is/c++draft/ranges#range.nonprop.cache-1.6) to be, filed [#102236](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102236)).

Note that (as 康桓瑋 points out in the comments), `std::ranges::distance` is the wrong length for the string_view, since you're not account for the extra space delimiters that are removed by the `split`. The `len` adjustment above should account for that correctly.

---

You cannot do it this way:

```cpp
constexpr auto rng = words | split(' ') | take(4) | std::views::join;
```

Because this would be `join`ing a range of prvalue ranges (from the `split`), and that case is not `const`-iterable (because we need to cache each sub-range that we're joining, which has to be cached into the `join_view` itself, which requires mutation, and so we can't do it).

The resulting object has to be mutable, which means you can't declare it `constexpr` (which is why my way above should work, once fully implemented).

---

> And as an aside, is there a more elegant way to build this `string_view`? The `&*` is particularly ugly.

Not really. In order for `views::join` to be able to reliably give you a contiguous range, it's not enough to know that we're `join`ing a range of contiguous ranges, we also have to know that those contiguous pieces are themselves contiguous. And... they're not in this case (because we're dropping the space delimiter). Even if there were some mechanism to preserve contiguity (and I have no idea what such a mechanism would look like), this wouldn't even be a valid place to apply it - we do *not* have a contiguous range here.

But in this case you know that those pieces happen to be contiguous, because you know everything about how we're constructing this pipeline and that this is a safe operation to do, because you know you want to keep in the spaces that are separating your contiguous subranges. But you're going outside of the ranges model here and doing something potentially unsafe, so that's just going to be a little ugly.

Comment: The `split` drops the delimiter so the joined range isn't contiguous to begin with?

Comment: `std::string_view(&*first_n.begin(), std::ranges::distance(first_n));` This makes `views::split` meaningless.

Comment: @康桓瑋 No it doesn't? It's successfully grabbing the first `n` words, still space delimited.

Comment: @Barry. Taking `str` as `"1 2 3 4 5"sv` and `n` as `4` as example, `first_n` will get `{'1','2','3','4'}` which has distance `4`, so `string_view(...)` will get `"1 2 3 4 5"sv.substr(0, 4)`, which is `"1 2 "`.